# Rails 5: Can't redirect after JS call (DropZoneJS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm trying to implement Drag&Drop functionality using *DropZoneJS* in my **Rails 5** app. I accomplished to upload the file, but the view isn't refreshing when the controller is called from JavaScript (works perfectly with normal upload).

The code (only the parts who matter for the case):

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:printing_file, url: new_printing_file_path, html: {method: :post, class: "dragdropzone"} ) do |f| %>
    <div>Drag&Drop a file here</div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(:printing_file, url: new_printing_file_path, html: {method: :post}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, class: "printing-file-upload-field", onchange: "this.form.submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

First form for Drag&Drop, second for regular upload (which is redirecting OK).

**printing_files.coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
  dropzone = new Dropzone('.dragdropzone',
    paramName: 'printing_file[file]'
    addRemoveLinks: false
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/javascript' })
```

**printing_files_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @printing_file = PrintingFile.new(printing_file_params)
  @printing_file.user = current_user
  @printing_file.name = printing_file_params[:file].original_filename
  if @printing_file.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to files_path, notice: "File was correctly uploaded." }
      format.js
    end
  else
    redirect_to files_path, alert: "There was an error while uploading file."
  end
end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
console.log("This is never printed");
window.location = "<%= files_path() %>";
```

I also tried in my `printing_files_controller.rb` several options found here like `render js` but none of them work.

**Output:**

> Processing by PrintingFilesController#new as JS
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PBX2dbP8p+aZZXOkIIw1oFg3QZ02mDo+u+Z02NrBFCE+aNT3gWzwFjmQeGmcBcBItkg6l899iGIxuJljWDl+zA==", "printing_file"=>{"file"=>#, @original_filename="9.stl", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"printing_file[file]\"; filename=\"9.stl\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}}
>
> Rendering printing_files/new.js.erb
>
> Rendered printing_files/new.js.erb (1.0ms)

Note that js file is rendering but the browser console is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're looking for Dropzone's success parameter:

```
$(document).ready ->
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
  dropzone = new Dropzone('.dragdropzone',
    paramName: 'printing_file[file]'
    addRemoveLinks: false
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/javascript' })
    success: () -> location.reload()
```

You can change the Javascript location inside that function.

Comment: Is a good approach but is reloading the entire page. I only want to reload the files view like `redirect_to` does.